# How to identify the full response body of refresh token API?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jwt, refresh-token

These are authentication & refresh token API developed for a mobile app. Can anyone help to identify the response body for the refresh token API based on this codes? I am somehow confused of the full response body. I believe the final response would be:

```
{
"success":true,
"message":"Refresh Token generated"
}
```

But what is the full response before that?

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Authenticate", tags = {})
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_OK, message = "The response body contains a boolean value and a message.", response = ResponseBase.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Bad Request.", response = ResponseBase.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, message = "Login failed.", response = ResponseBase.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE, message = "Make sure specify 'application/json' as the media type.", response = ResponseBase.class),
            @ApiResponse(code = HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "Internal Server Error", response = ResponseBase.class)
    })
    @RequestMapping(value = Constants.REST_API_AUTH, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createAuthenticationToken(@RequestBody @Valid AuthenticationRequest request) throws Exception {

        String msg = null;

        try {
            authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getUsername(), request.getUsername())
            );
        } catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
            msg = "Incorrect username or password";
        } catch (AccountStatusException e) {
            msg = e.getMessage();
        }
        if (null != msg) {
            msg = "Login failed: " + msg;
            String detail = request.toString();
            log.info(msg);
            throw new RestApiException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, false, msg, detail);
        }

        if (smsUtil.isSGNumber(request.getUsername())) {
            String result = otpService.checkOtp(request.getUsername(), request.getPassword());
            msg = "Login failed: OTP " + result;
            if (Constants.OTP_STATUS_EXP.equals(result) || Constants.OTP_STATUS_MIS.equals(result)) {
                throw new RestApiException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, false, msg, msg);
            }
        }

        final UserDetail userDetail = new UserDetail(request.getUsername(), "");

        final String token = jwtTokenUtil.generateToken(userDetail);

        ResponseBase body = new ResponseBase();
        msg = "Login successful";
        log.info("{} : {}", msg, request);
        body.setSuccess(true);
        body.setMessage(msg);
        return httpUtil.createResponseEntityJson(HttpStatus.OK, httpUtil.createSecTokenHeader(token), body);
    }


    @GetMapping(value = Constants.REST_API_REFRESH_TOKEN)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getRefreshToken(@RequestHeader(Constants.HTTP_AUTH_HEADER) String authHeader, HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("Generate refresh token");
        String token = httpUtil.extractSecurityToken(authHeader);
        ResponseBase body = new ResponseBase();
        body.setSuccess(true);
        body.setMessage("Refresh Token generated");

        String refreshToken;
        DefaultClaims claims = (io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultClaims) request.getAttribute("claims");
        if(null == claims) {
            refreshToken = jwtTokenUtil.renewToken(token);
        } else {
            refreshToken = jwtTokenUtil.renewToken(claims);
        }
        return httpUtil.createResponseEntityJson(HttpStatus.OK, httpUtil.createSecTokenHeader(refreshToken), body);
    }
}
```

From the last line `return httpUtil.createResponseEntityJson(HttpStatus.OK, httpUtil.createSecTokenHeader(refreshToken), body);`, the `createSecTokenHeader` will call this:

```
public HttpHeaders createSecTokenHeader(String token) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set(Constants.HTTP_AUTH_HEADER, Constants.HTTP_AUTH_HEADER_BEARER + token);
        return headers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you stated the response is given as:

```
{
   "success":true,
   "message":"Refresh Token generated"
}
```

from the code:

```
return httpUtil.createResponseEntityJson(HttpStatus.OK, httpUtil.createSecTokenHeader(refreshToken), body);
```

But I believe the refresh token comes from the header with the

```
httpUtil.createSecTokenHeader(refreshToken)
```

Comment: Hi, I just updated my question. Can you take a look at it and tell me if I can provide more info for you to figure out the full response body? Really need help.

Comment: It seems that the response from getRefreshToken(), generates a token and adds it to header appending to "BEARER " i.e.
`BEARER {refresh_token}` and assigns it to Constants.HTTP_AUTH_HEADER

When you execute it, check the network tab in the browser and the headers to find the refresh token.